# ~ The important use of Frobenius–Schur indicators and Frobenius-Schur exponents ~

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, representation-theory, quantum-groups

I had asked a question on [the uses of conjugacy class and centralizer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731982/the-use-of-conjugacy-class-and-centralizer). I had receive various helpful feedback. I appreciate them. Here I like to get some feedback on the Frobenius–Schur indicator.

> $\bullet$ What is the important use of [Frobenius–Schur indicators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator)? Why such a notion is important? What are examples that using Frobenius–Schur indicators can help us classifying some vector spaces or (discrete) groups?
>
> $\bullet$ How about **Frobenius-Schur exponents**(e.g. [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603191v3.pdf) and [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601012v3.pdf))?

It seems to me that if I understand that the concept of discrete Fourier transformation for the finite group, the Frobenius–Schur indicators to be some-sort of invariance or measure.

> $\bullet$ It is said that Frobenius-Schur indicators have values of 0, +1, -1; but I find [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603191v3.pdf) define **the higher Frobenius-Schur indicators** $\nu^{(n)}$, which has values larger than $1$, such as $\nu^{(n)}=2$ in the page 22's Appendix. Can someone address why this is the case that **the higher Frobenius-Schur indicators** $\nu^{(n)}$ may not be 0, +1, -1?

-

p.s. I had learned that Frobenius-Schur indicators/exponents are useful to classify certain [Spherical Categories](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601012v3.pdf). Maybe someone can also say a few words about this direction?